# Time limit exceeded. whats wrong?

Tags: python

Given an array of integers, perform at most `K` operations so that the sum of elements of final array is minimum. An operation is defined as follows -

Consider any 1 element from the array, `arr[i]`.

Replace `arr[i]` by `floor(arr[i]/2)`.

Perform next operations on updated array.

The task is to minimize the sum after at most `K` operations.
Input

```
4 3

20 7 5 4
```

Output

```
17
```

Explanation

Operation 1 -> Select 20. Replace it by 10.

New array = `[10, 7, 5, 4]`.

Operation 2 -> Select 10. Replace it by 5.

New array = `[5, 7, 5, 4]`.

Operation 3 -> Select 7. Replace it by 3.

New array = `[5,3,5,4]`.

Sum = 17.

This is what i tried

```
a,b= input().split(" ")
  
n=int(a)
k=int(b)
arr=list(map(int,input().split()))

arr.sort(reverse=True)
i=0
while k>0 and i<n:
  if arr[i]<0:
    i+=1
  else:
    arr[i]=arr[i]//2
    k-=1
    if max(arr)!=arr[i]:
      i+=1
    

print(sum(arr),end="")
```

Comment: I don't think this will give the correct answer because an item which is no longer the maximum (and you do your `i+=1`) might become the maximum again later after you have changed other items. But apart from that, you will somehow need to find a way to avoid calling `max` on every iteration because it has to scan through everything.

Answer (score -1):

I can see the typo in division operator `arr[i]=arr[i]**//**2`

Comment: // is the floor division operator, look it up in the Python documentation.